# I cannot delete a duplicate folder in IMAP

Tags: microsoft-outlook, gmail, imap, microsoft-outlook-2013

I was using Outlook 2013 to copy all my e-mails from an old gmail account to a new one with IMAP.  When I ran the copy, instead of putting all the e-mails into matching folders inside the `[Gmail]` folder, it ended creating a `[Gmail] - Copy`.

[image: doubled gmail folder]

I want to delete the copy (or delete the original and rename the copy so my e-mails get moved), but I cannot.  All the options for deleting, renaming, etc are grayed out.

[image: buttons grayed out]

Comment: IMAP updates the server information also.  Are you able to deleted it on the server?

Comment: @Ramhound `[Gmail] - Copy` does not show up in my gmail.

Comment: Is Outlook by chance trying to update the server.  If its a large amount of data it might take awhile.

Comment: @Ramhound I do not see an active sync operation.  And I can delete individual messages with no problem.